# Latex "algorithm2e" giving error while writing an algorithm in IEEEAccess template

Tags: texstudio, overleaf, algorithm2e

I am trying to compile a tex file in overleaf, I am using IEEEAccess template to write the manuscript. When I compile the latex throws the error on the given algorithm script.
I am showing the initial page too with the environments.
Environments:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[ruled,lined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\cb}{\textcolor{blue}}
\newcommand{\cred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\cg}{\textcolor{green}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

The script for the algorithm.

```
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
\SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    
    \Input{$G =\left \langle N,E,W \right \rangle:$ graph network, $B\left(G_{i}\right):$ Set of boundary nodes, $E_{b}:$ Set of boundary edges}
    \Output{$G_{emb}:$ Embedded Graph Network}
    %initialize $Dist_{mat}\left(k,v\right) \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
    \protect Step-1: Compute the shortest path from each boundary node to another boundary node\\
    \ForEach{boundary node $n^{b}_{i} \in B\left(G_{i}\right)$}{
        \emph{SPList} $\left(B_{spf}\right) \leftarrow YenAlgorithm.runSP\left(G, srcVertex, destVertex\right)$
    
    }
    \KwRet{$\emph{SPList} \left(B_{sp}\right)$}
    \protect Step-2: Create an Embedded network by unifying the shortest-path list\\
    $G_{emb} \leftarrow \emptyset$ \tcp*{Create a new empty graph}
    \ForEach{$e_{ij} \in E_{b}$}{
        $G_{emb} \leftarrow \emph{addEdge}\left(e_{ij}\right)$
    }
    \ForEach{\emph{shortest-path} $\left(B_{sp}\right) \in \emph{SPList} \left(B_{sp}\right)$}{
        \If{$e_{ij} \in E_{b}$}{
            \If{$n^{b}_{i}.partitionId = n^{b}_{j}.partitionId$}{
                $G_{emb} \leftarrow \emph{addEdge}\left(e_{ij}\right)$}}
    }
    \KwRet{$G_{emb}$}
 \caption{Embedded Graph Construction}
    \label{alg:embGraph}
\end{algorithm}
```

The file compiles however, the algorithm adds negative -2 in front of the line numbers.
[![The output of the algorithm][1]][1]

The errors are:
Argument of \relsize  has an extra }.
Argument of \relsize  has an extra }.
Argument of \relsize  has an extra }.
Runaway argument?
Argument of @algocf@endoption has an extra }.

The errors are in the following lines:
[![Overleaf Script][2]][2]

How do I solve this issue? The tex file compiles completely fine if I remove the algorithm part.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE5Gl.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYlyv.png

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just add these 3 lines of code in the latex file.

```
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\LaTeXtextbf}{\textbf}
\LetLtxMacro{\textbf}{\LaTeXtextbf}

\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
```

Once I added these lines and compiled them, the algorithms were back to normal with the correct line numbers.